# Minimal number of coefficient changes to turn a matrix into invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n >0 $ an integer. Find the smallest integer $p$ such that *every* matrix $M$ of size $n \times n$ can get invertible if we allow to change $p$ coefficients in $M$.

Obviously $p \geqslant n$ because the null matrix requires $n$ coefficients change to be invertible. I think that $p=n$ is optimal.

Any ideas for proving the converse ?

I only proved it in dimension $2$ ...

Comment: An alternative approach is to note that matrix rank coincides with [tensor rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition).  We can consider "changing coefficients" to be an instance of adding a rank-1 matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For any matrix $A$ and a sufficiently large $\lambda > 0$, the matrix $A + \lambda I$ is invertible.  *($I$ denotes the identity matrix)*

Comment: In fact, for all but finitely many $\lambda$.

Comment: How could I have not seen that ... of course it work when $-\lambda$ is not in the spectrum !